# How to share mongo docker volumes between hosts

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I cant find a solid way of doing this, But i have a container that runs mongo and it has data in it, Im trying to find a way to have this data shared between people, The data will likely change sometimes and need updating.

I have a docker compose file that runs the front and backend of my app and i want to share this so that others can open up the app along with the data i have created for it

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: How theses people should see the data? Do they have Linux users? If yes, you can create a group for them and add them in that group, then change the permissions of that folder so that they all would access to read, write and execute.

Comment: No, Everyone uses a mac - Add a group where?

Comment: No, I mean place that data is shared is inside a server, right? Or it's in a Mac laptop locally?

Comment: Apologies... My docker knowledge is limited. The volume is just stored locally on my coomputer - I have a docker compose file that runs the front and backend of my app and i want to share this so that others can open up the app along with the data i have created for it

Comment: Then that does not do have anything with Docker I think. You should I think you should search how to share a folder between other users in Mac. Then you can map the volume to that shared folder, so other people connecting to the network you have created from your laptop will be able to see that shared folder.

Comment: Or maybe just put that mongodb on a server where everyone has access? Or is that some sort of test database which everyone should use to start with the same set of data for development or something like that? In that case [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) is probably a better solution.

Comment: I have tried the mongo dump solution but it doesnt work as i cant have multiple volumes that look at the same folder therefore can not save the volume to my local computer

Comment: Why do you want to map multiple volumes to the same folder?

Comment: I want to be able to send this volume with my mongodb data to a coworker

Comment: Are you in the same location? I mean do you work in a place where you go there every day and see each other? Or you all work remote?